# Setting video as div background?

Tags: html, video, background

I'm looking to set a server-side video as the background of a div. I would like the text (h1) to sit on top of it. Is there a way to make the video completely fill the div and hide the overflow/be responsive? The div is 100% width and a set height.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Have you had a go at doing this yourself? What did you try and how did it fail? Can you please edit your question and add the code you tried (even if it isn't working)? Have you had a google for this subject? if so - what did you find? ie... please show us you've at least made some effort at solving this yourself... we like to help people who show research effort :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <video class="videoInsert" controls autoplay>
        <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <div class="video">
            <h1>text here </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```